# Process Handling in cgi

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cgi

I am doing simple web programming using c++ in Apache, Linux. I created a cgi script called `signup.cgi`. This program gets input from browser and write the data in a file called `users.txt`.

My question is, when two user access the `signup.cgi`, will it be create two different processes or only one process?

**Case 1:** Will it be two different Processes to access `users.txt`?

```
User1 ----> singup.cgi -----> Pid1 ----> users.txt
User1 ----> singup.cgi -----> Pid2 ----> users.txt
```

(or)

**Case 2:** Will it be only one process to access `users.txt`?

```
User1 ----> singup.cgi -----> Pid1 ----> users.txt
User1 ----> singup.cgi -----> Pid1 ----> users.txt
```

If It is two different processes access `users.txt` in same time, data in `users.txt` will be corrupt. How can I handle this Issue?

If It is only one process to access `users.txt`, I don't know what are the problems that I may get?

Comment: Did you try, writing the pid to the file ?

Comment: do you mean in users.txt?

Comment: yes exactly ! Or in a log file

Comment: @Christophe: I understand the concept from you question. Thank you.

Comment: Consider using a small `sqlite` database to insert the users into and create the username field with the `unique` qualifier so you can't insert the same user twice - the second one will get an error.

Comment: I think, and I am happy to be corrected, that the answer to your question is that it depends how your webserver is set up. In the general, simple case, it would be a different process for each client, but if you use `FastCGI` or similar, two users could be handled by threads of a single process.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's use of processes depends on how your server and your CGI "script" are configured.  According to [RFC 3875](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875):

- The CGI "script" that is invoked by the server can be a standalone program, a
  dynamically-loaded or shared library, a subroutine in the (Apache software) server, or an interpreted script (See section 1.4)
- "*The most common implementation of CGI invokes the script as a child
  process using the same user and group as the server process.*" (See section 9.5). But the [FastCGI variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI), which manages a pool of processes, to avoid the overhead of launching new processes for each request.
- The script should be stateless.  See section 9.7:

> The stateless nature of the Web makes **each** script **execution** and    resource retrieval independent of all
>   others even when multiple    requests constitute a single conceptual
>   Web transaction.  Because of    this, a script **should not make any
>   assumptions** about the context of    the user-agent submitting a
>   request.

To reinforce this fundamental recommendation, think that in scalable operations you may have a load balancer that routes incoming http request to one of many apache server, and the apache server could route the requests to one or of several FastCGI services. If you think stateless, you'll be safe !

So in conclusion: in your CGI program you can't assume nothing about processes and users (you have to manage sessions if you have to put related requests together).

And yes, if several processes write to the same file in the same moment, you could get real garbage in your file.  You'll have to use OS level [interprocess synchronisation mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to manage that.  Semaphores or file locks could sequentialize file access but decrease performance.  memory mapped files could help in an easier fashion.

But to overcome this limitation, you'll have to achieve an architectural quantum leap.  The topic is far too broead to be developped here, but for example:

- use of a message queue:  each process sends data to a message queue (in another process) that will handle it as soon as it can, but without delaying the request processing.
- use a service oriented architecture,  where each process routes request to a service, such as for example a database or object persistence layer.